# Python Azure SDK Uploading a Blob

Tags: php, python, azure

I am trying to pass a file from PHP into Python where I can upload to Azure Blob Storage via the Azure Python SDK.

PHP:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /opt/UploadFile.py $filePath $container $blob");
die(var_dump($output));
```

Python:

```
import sys
from azure.storage import BlobService

upload = sys.argv[1];
container = sys.argv[2]; 
blob = sys.argv[3];
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='HIDDEN', account_key='HIDDEN')


try:
    blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
        continer,
        blob,
        upload
    )
except:
    print "error"
```

I am getting the catch exception. I have verified that the variables are coming over correctly from PHP. Not sure why its not working. I am new to Python what else can I do to debug that the .put_block_blob_from_path() is working?

Comment: Instead of printing just the string "error", you could try printing the actual error message. See this link for try/catch reference in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html. Also print "container", "blob" and "upload" variable values to see correct values are being passed. HTH.

Comment: I printed the container, blob, and upload they are correct and being passed in correctly

Comment: How about printing the actual error message?

Comment: That is what I am looking at to do now. I see lots of exceptions like IO,etc. I am trying to find just a basic catch all exception for my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out if I added

```
print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

in the except:.

I would get a nice print of the error.